# CloudWatch log multiple custom metric filters to trigger lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I just start learning on aws, and I have created couple of cloudwatch log custom metric filter and subscribe to the same lambda function do to some stuff, but I want to get my lambda function to perform difference action depends on which metric filter trigger it. In the lambda function(in python) how can I know which metric filter trigger it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Lambda function handlers, you'll have an event object, this object will usually contain information about the request. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-cloudwatch-logs), this is base64 encoded and zipped. I imagine this is because the logs are expected to get fairly large.

Once unzipped the structure is:

```
{ messageType: 'DATA_MESSAGE',
  owner: '123456789123',
  logGroup: 'testLogGroup',
  logStream: 'testLogStream',
  subscriptionFilters: [ 'testFilter' ],
  logEvents: 
   [ { id: 'eventId1',
       timestamp: 1440442987000,
       message: '[ERROR] First test message' },
     { id: 'eventId2',
       timestamp: 1440442987001,
       message: '[ERROR] Second test message' } ] }
```

This can be found in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) under CloudWatch Logs.

You can check on the `subscriptionFilters` field in the event data to check which filter triggered the Lambda.

If your Lambda was in NodeJS, you could write something like the following:

```
const zlib = require('zlib');
const YOUR_FILTER = 'filter1';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const zippedInput = new Buffer(event.awslogs.data, 'base64');
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        zlib.gunzip(zippedInput, function (e, buffer) {
            const awslogsData = JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf-8'));
            // Conditions on filters to do something
            if (awslogsData.subscriptionFilters.includes(YOUR_FILTER)) {
                // do something
            } else if (awslogsData.subscriptionFilters.includes('your_other_filter')) {
                // do something else
            }

            resolve();
        });
    })

    return 'Hello from Lambda!'
};
```

Comment: I need to do it in python, and I saw some example on the net to decode and unzip the log data the following is part of my function:

`def lambda_handler(event, context):

    outEvent = str(event['awslogs']['data'])    
    outEvent = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(outEvent.decode('base64','strict'))).read()`

But it return the following error:
`'str' object has no attribute 'decode': AttributeError
:
outEvent = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(outEvent.decode('base64','strict'))).read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`
How to resolve this error?

Comment: String.decode was removed in python3, you should import base64 and do something like `base64.b64decode(outEvent)` instead.